# How to access a list's length in a template's code block for Django?

Tags: python, django, web, backend, web-development-server

In a template, I have a variable of type list called "participants". I want to check if the length of the list is equal to 2, for example. I tried the following:

```
{{ participants | json_script:"participants"}}

{% if participants|length==2 %}

.....
{% endif %}
```

However, this does not work. The error I get is:

TemplateSyntaxError at /chat/lobby/
Could not parse the remainder: '==2' from 'participants.count==2'

Can someone point out a way to access a list's length in a template's code block? thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: adding few points to @MeL comment, create custom template filter take for calculating length. Such as `{% if participants|length:2 %}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the (lack of) spacing around the `==` part. If you rewrite this to

```
{% if participants|length == 2 %}
…
{% endif %}
```

the template parser will no longer error.

That being said, a template is used for *rendering* logic, and while it is hard to tell, it looks that this is more *business* logic, which, as [@MeL says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321760/how-to-access-a-lists-length-in-a-templates-code-block-for-django/63321784#comment111970528_63321760) belongs in the views.

Comment: I love Django, but disagree with this "philosophy" of making templates as dumb as possible. That might've made sense in 2005, but responsive, front-end development is a different ballgame in 2020. You may find this handy: https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/

Comment: Thank you! I added space around the "==", and it works now.

Comment: @FlipperPA: you can also make use of Jinja for a template engine that gives "full python" expression power: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/. You can just use this as a template engine, since you do not *have* to use the Django engine.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Jinja2 as well, but sometimes it is overkill. :) Thanks!